# C++ Compiler Error: "No matching function for call", when using a 2-D array as an argument

Tags: c++, function, arguments, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to call a function (called closestPair) in a separate .cpp file from my main.cpp, using a [5][10] 2D-array as an argument.

The call:

```
extern const unsigned int vSize = 10;

[...]

double input[5][10] = {{0.595500, 0.652927, 0.606763, 0.162761, 0.980752, 0.964772, 0.319322, 0.611325, 0.012422, 0.393489},
                       {0.416132, 0.778858, 0.909609, 0.094812, 0.380586, 0.512309, 0.638184, 0.753504, 0.465674, 0.674607},
                       {0.183963, 0.933146, 0.476773, 0.086125, 0.566566, 0.728107, 0.837345, 0.885175, 0.600559, 0.142238},
                       {0.086523, 0.025236, 0.252289, 0.089437, 0.382081, 0.420934, 0.038498, 0.626125, 0.468158, 0.247754},
                       {0.969345, 0.127753, 0.736213, 0.264992, 0.518971, 0.216767, 0.390992, 0.242241, 0.516135, 0.990155}};
closestPair(input);
```

The header:

```
#include <iostream>

extern const unsigned int vSize;
double vectDistance (double a[], double b[]);
void closestPair(double bag[][vSize]);

#endif /* defined(__Cpp_Lab2__name1__) */
```

The function:

```
void closestPair(double bag[][vSize]){
 [...]
}
```

The error:

```
No matching function for call to 'closestPair'
```

I think something in the input 2D-array seems to be conflicting with the argument list for the function, but I'm not sure what the issue could be. I've checked all over the place, and it's probably something stupid that I'm missing. How can I solve that?

Comment: I am not sure this is standard c++: `void closestPair(double bag[][vSize]);`? `vSize` has to be known at compile time, not at link time. Can you post the entire error message?

Comment: `In file included from /[...]/double_arrays.h:16:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'double [5][10]' to 'double (*)[vSize]' for 1st argument
void closestPair(double bag[][vSize]);
     ^
1 error generated.`

Comment: @bdnk [Works fine](http://ideone.com/fPkXAl).  Please post a complete program that shows the problem (and you have verified that it shows the problem). Currently you have just posted bits and pieces, so there may be a transscription error, or you may have left out something important.

Comment: Removing vSize from the function arguments and replacing it with the value 10, solved my problem. I don't know enough about this language yet to tell why, but thanks for everyone's help

Answer (score 0):

Try to using something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void closestPair(double *input, size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        cout << input[i] << endl;
}

int main() {
    size_t vSize = 10;
    double input[5][10] = {{0.595500, 0.652927, 0.606763, 0.162761, 0.980752, 0.964772, 0.319322, 0.611325, 0.012422, 0.393489},
                       {0.416132, 0.778858, 0.909609, 0.094812, 0.380586, 0.512309, 0.638184, 0.753504, 0.465674, 0.674607},
                       {0.183963, 0.933146, 0.476773, 0.086125, 0.566566, 0.728107, 0.837345, 0.885175, 0.600559, 0.142238},
                       {0.086523, 0.025236, 0.252289, 0.089437, 0.382081, 0.420934, 0.038498, 0.626125, 0.468158, 0.247754},
                       {0.969345, 0.127753, 0.736213, 0.264992, 0.518971, 0.216767, 0.390992, 0.242241, 0.516135, 0.990155}};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        closestPair(input[i], vSize);
    return 0;
}
```

Use a pointer to access to your array. (Be careful with the indexes.)

Other option:

```
void closestPair(double *input, size_t xSize, size_t ySize) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < xSize; ++i) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < ySize; ++i)
            cout << input[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    size_t xSize = 5;
    size_t ySize = 10;
    double input[5][10] = {{0.595500, 0.652927, 0.606763, 0.162761, 0.980752, 0.964772, 0.319322, 0.611325, 0.012422, 0.393489},
                       {0.416132, 0.778858, 0.909609, 0.094812, 0.380586, 0.512309, 0.638184, 0.753504, 0.465674, 0.674607},
                       {0.183963, 0.933146, 0.476773, 0.086125, 0.566566, 0.728107, 0.837345, 0.885175, 0.600559, 0.142238},
                       {0.086523, 0.025236, 0.252289, 0.089437, 0.382081, 0.420934, 0.038498, 0.626125, 0.468158, 0.247754},
                       {0.969345, 0.127753, 0.736213, 0.264992, 0.518971, 0.216767, 0.390992, 0.242241, 0.516135, 0.990155}};

    closestPair(input[0], xSize, ySize);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get a similar error message to before, saying that there exists no known conversion between the input and the expected argument. I'm quite new to C++, could you explain what your solution is supposed to change?

Comment: I changed my answer. In C/C++, arrays are "contiguous memory locations".

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
const unsigned int vSize = 10;
```

in both files.

That will make sure that the type of the input to `closestPair` is `double (*)[10]` and not `double (*)[vSize]`.

Comment: It doesn't appear to have made any change. The same error message displays, even when the variable exists in both files.

Comment: Did you make the change in the .h file?

Comment: I am out of further ideas.